# How do I work with class properties that only have a value once an observable has resolved?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a common problem I'm facing when working with angular2+. I have a property in my service that only gets a value assigned to it once an observable that's defined in the constructor is resolved (for example an `http` call below). I can either assign the observable to the property itself, and subscribe to the property in other components(1), or I can assign a value to the property in the `.subscribe` call (2).

(1)

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public property;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.property = this.http.get(url).map((res) => res.json());
  }
}
```

(2)

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public property;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      (value) => this.property = value.json()
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that in case (2), I can't figure out how to handle the property in other components that consume the service, since given the async nature of observables it always resolves to `undefined`. I'm not concerned about handling it in the template but rather in the TS code.

I can't always use case (1) because sometimes I need the response to be assigned to multiple values.

Comment: You should always properly chain async calls with `map`, `then` or similar. In view bindings you can use `field?.prop` to not get errors when `field` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm not too concerned with templating, I know that I can use the async pipe or safe navigation operator. I'm more concerned with using the properties in components - that's more what my question is directed towards, sorry I should have specified that.

Comment: "it always resolves to undefined" is an incorrect assumption. It is probably only undefined if the async call that assigns a value to it isn't completed yet, so the value will be set later. You need to ensure that 2 is called after 1 is completed. This is what I mean with chaining async calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that your problem is that on of your component triggers your service to make request. Then other components need that information also. If you use separate Observable then you can make getter and setter for that property. Here is exemple about this in my app https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/angular2App/app/services/playlist.service.ts
Check how my components are using getPlaylistsModified() and how Service itself is using setter funktion.

Comment: That still wouldn't work though. It can be simplified this way: I have a service. That service calls `this.http.get().subscribe()` in the constructor. In the `.subscribe` call I assign the output to multiple values (i.e. `(value) => {this.title = value.title;})`. The problem is that this is done asynchronously - when a component injects the service and tries to call the property in most instances the value will still be `undefined`. How do I use those properties that are assigned in `.subscribe()` in other components?

Comment: I still recommend that you use this Observable pattern. If you subscribe in you component for that  getter and start your call after you first time get different value than null or undefined. Check this out how I use subscriptionPlaylistsModified in here https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/angular2App/app/modules/tracklist/tracklist.component.ts